# Want to prevent user from entering any space in textfield by providing error when he does

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, qtip

I have a textfield in Extjs. This textfield can only contain

- `Digits 0 - 9`
- `Alphabets a-z or A-Z`
- Characters like `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen)

I want to prevent the user from entering anything apart from these characters. As such I wish to display an error, something like a red underline along with `helptext` to notify the user as to why the error is there.

Kindly advice as to how to go about preventing the user from entering anything apart from the above characters and also displaying the error message.

Comment: `^[\w-]+$` ..............

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried, what didn't work?

Comment: Hi, I have used regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/ as a way to validate. But the problem is that this doesnt prevent the user from entering invalid input. It just notifies the user that what he's entering is invalid

Comment: So it is not a problem of creating the correct RegExp but more how to deal with the user entry itself. Show us the code that you are using then we can give you some help or advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`maskRe`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-maskRe) property:

> An input mask regular expression that will be used to filter
>   keystrokes (character being typed) that do not match. Note: It does
>   not filter characters already in the input.

```
maskRe: /[A-Za-z0-9\-_]/
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/o4b

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had done this but the issue is this doesn't prevent the user from entering invalid input. It just displays an invalid input statement and the red line.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. There are a whole load of issues with [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) and [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) on different browsers, but I believe this should work on most/all modern browsers without issue.

```js
var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error'),
    testInp = document.getElementById('test');

testInp.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt) {
    var code = evt.keyCode || evt.charCode;

    if (code >= 48 && code <= 57 || code >= 65 && code <= 90 || code >= 97 && code <= 122 || code === 45 || code === 95) {

        errorDiv.classList.add('hidden');
    } else {
        evt.preventDefault();
        errorDiv.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
}, false);

testInp.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
    var code = evt.keyCode || evt.charCode;

    if (code === 8 || code >= 37 && code <= 40|| code === 46) {
        errorDiv.classList.add('hidden');
    }
}, false);
```

```css
#error {
    color: red;
}
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" />
<div id="error" class="hidden">As such I wish to display an error, something like a red underline along with helptext to notify the user as to why the error is there.</div>
```

Comment: Never thought of it this way. Although this is the longer way of doing it but, nevertheless, its logical. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: There is a little more to type with pure JS but this is essentially what is going on under the bonnet of your library. The library just gives you some sugar. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event keyup and check the input key value.

For example for a space:

```
listeners: {
        keyup: function(field, e) {
             var key = e.getKey(); 
             if (key == 32){
                 alert("Hey dude, what are you doing?");
             }
       }
 }
```

Or something else. You can take a look at:

```
field.addClass("x-form-invalid")
field.markInvalid("Hey dude, what are you doing?");
```

Hope this helps.